# Connecting multiple hubs to a single Z-Wave device

Tags: home-automation

First off, please forgive me if this is not the right Stack Exchange site for this. I figured this was the best option.

Is it possible to hook up multiple hubs/controllers to a single Z-Wave device? For example, if I have a GE Simon XT alarm system control panel that is Z-Wave compatible and paired with a Z-Wave light switch, could I also hook up a Wink Hub to that same light switch and control it from either one? Or better yet, could I tap into an existing motion sensor from my security system with a Wink Hub?

Comment: I would investigate Home Assistant, as it can be your primary and sole brain for home automation, eliminating all of the other "required hubs."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Z-Wave specification, no. A Z-Wave node (device) can only be paired to one hub (the designated 'primary' controller). 'Secondary' controllers added to the primary controller will lose their z-wave netword/added nodes and just act as a relay remote control. I don't believe adding the Wink Hub as a secondary controller is the option you're looking for since you will lose any nodes added to it and you will have to re-add them to your primary controller (your GE Simon XT for instance).

However, some controllers, such as Vera and VeraLite, allow you to bridge two or more controllers via ethernet/wi-fi and to pass-through Z-Wave requests to devices present on either controller. The controllers remain independent of each other from a Z-Wave point of view, an communicate to each other via your ethernet/wi-fi network. I have not come across this funcionality in GE Simon XT and Wink hubs.

With the Vera Z-wave controllers, as an example of increasing range and reliability, you can:

Install one Vera on your ground-floor. Pair ground-floor nodes to this Vera.

Install another Vera on on your first-floor. Pair second-floor nodes to this Vera.

Designate one Vera as your 'main' Vera (that is, the one you'd use to control via the web, iOS app, Z-Wave remotes, etc - your go-to controller basically). Under this Vera's config, select Add Devices and choose UPNP devices.

The 'main' Vera will then locate the 'other' Vera on your LAN and show the nodes on the 'main' Vera's device panel. You can then control the 'other' nodes via your 'main' Vera. The 'main' Vera will send the required commands via LAN to the 'other' Vera to be sent via Z-Wave to it's associated nodes.

Comment: So if I'm understanding right, I could basically pair my Simon XT to a Vera controller and effectively be able to switch lights (or other Z-Wave devices) from either interface?

Comment: @xboxremote see my new edited answer above. You can only have one primary controller in a z-wave network. So you will need to be careful as doing so may mean you will lose any nodes added to the secondary controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to z-wave / home improvement but looks like some people are saying it should be possible using geekier controller called `OpenHAB`. See [another thread](https://community.openhab.org/t/z-wave-binding-with-multiple-controllers/11056/8).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using home assistant hub and wink hub.
You can have either or all Zwave device connected to home assistant or some connected to wink hub. All device will be reachable throughout home assistant interface.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Z-wave networks can have multiple controllers, in fact, it is fundamental to how devices communicate with one another.

A good starting point for understanding Z-wave networks is "Z-Wave Network Protocol Command Class Specification", which is a public document describing Z-wave networks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/141247)